# Set values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in a way that given series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

### Problem

We have series defined as:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}x^{n} $$

Define $x$ in a way that the series is convergent when $x \in \mathbb{R}$

### Attempt to solve

I would start off simply with some trial and error.

$x=0 \quad \text{everything is 0}$

$x=1  \quad 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\dots \quad \text{converges} \rightarrow 2$

$x=2 \quad 2+2+\frac{8}{3}+4\dots \quad \text{diverges}\rightarrow \infty$

$x=3 \quad 3+\frac{9}{2}+9+\frac{81}{4}\dots \quad \text{diverges}\rightarrow \infty$

If we try to insert negative x values we can note that there is $x^n$ which means every $x\in(2,4,6,8,\dots)$ will give positive value and every $x\in(1,3,5,7,9,\dots)$ will give negative value. Doesn't seem it would be convergent. Mayby divergent but there isn't enough proof of this.

I would say this series is convergent when $ 0 < x < 1 $

There is possibly more definitive way to find out all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ values that the series will converge. If someone can help with this that would be highly appreciated.

(Also i am not implying this would be considered as the correct solution)

Comment: What do you mean by "define $x$ in a way..."? Do you mean to find conditions on $x$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I want to find out all values of $x$ that will result in convergent series.

Comment: $x=1$ does not converge to $2$...

Comment: You might want to  re-check wether $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ converges

Comment: Notice that$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14>2$$so your $x=1$ is wrong.

Comment: I would recommend applying the ratio test, then applying different tests to check the convergence at the boundaries.

Comment: This series does converge for $x<1$, but not for $x=1$.

Comment: And for example for $x=-1$, it converges to $-log(2)$.

Comment: @Insertnamehere how did you compute the exact value for this ?

Comment: @Tuki It is a well-known series known as the alternating harmonic series for $x=-1$.

Comment: This is the taylor series around $0$ of $-log(1-x)$.

Comment: @Insertnamehere i don't doubt it but how can you work with taylor series in inverse. I know how to define taylor series for a given function but how to define function when the series is known ?

Comment: I would spot it by taking the derivative termwise w.r.t. $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

For the series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, compute the limit

$L = \lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$, according to [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test):

- if $L<1$, the series converges absolutely.
- if $L>1$, the series diverges,
- if $L=1$ or undefined, the test is not conclusive.

Also reading on [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) might help you with the boundary case.

Comment: Hm, you sure have grown quite a bit of hair these past few days. ;)

Comment: it's the new shampoo...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Read the following Wikipedia articles:

- [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem)
- [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))
- [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)